# ASP.NET 4 sites taking much longer than usual to restart

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7

Note: I am fully aware that ASP.NET website projects will recompile when you edit code-behind files, anything in App_Code, web.config, etc.  This question is not about that.  It's about an outrageous difference in time taken between .NET 3.5 and .NET 4 sites on the same server.

We have an issue with new .NET 4 web sites (but not .NET 3.5) taking MUCH longer than usual - two minutes extra - to restart or recompile.  More specifically, there is a long delay before the site will even start recompiling.  During this delay there is 0% (zero) CPU usage.

It seems that on any change that would normally trigger a recompile, there is a long, two minute delay before the compiler even kicks in on the server.  This is suspiciously the same duration as the timeout limit.  I have a suspicion that something is failing in .NET 4 or IIS7, and the site is not recompiling normally, until the timeout is reached and then it recycles the application pool and recompiles as usual.  Once it actually begins to recompile, the CPU spikes as expected, and it completes in about the same time that our .NET 3.5 sites do.

It is not due to the complexity of the site, as a pretty much identical site in .NET 3.5 does not cause the delay.  It is not specific to one site either, as all .NET 4 websites we deploy are experiencing the same issue.

Has anyone had any experience with a site in .NET 4 delaying for a several minutes before it recompiles a web site?

Comment: Have you considered pre-compiling the page? By pre-compiling it before publishing it can save a lot of time the first time the page is accesed. If you don't then it will get automatically compiled when first accessed. Of the queston - I'm not experiencing the same problems as you...

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, unfortunately pre-compiling isn't an option. It's affecting a local development server when code changes, the issue isn't with speed on a production environment.

Comment: Can you check if you have any lock mechanism on application ends ?

Comment: Sorry @Aristos I'm not sure what you mean, could you please explain?

Comment: @Andy on global.asax there is the application ends, do you run any code there ? Also there are other modules that can also runs the application ends - do you know if you have any that runs any code there ?

Comment: Ah, thanks @Aristos I understand. No, we're running an unmodified copy of a CMS that works totally fine under other versions of the .NET framework. And I can't find anything in the executed on Application End that might be locking.  I'm not sure how that would only affect .NET 4 but not .NET 3.5 anyway.

Comment: More info: changing the application pool to run in 32-bit mode seems to remove the delay.